# Adding GIT support to existing project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

I have multi-module project built with Maven. I imported only single sub-module (not parent) from that project as IDEA project, and looks like IDE doesn't recognize .git folder (because it is one level up from project root I used to import, I guess)

Is there still a possibility to add Git support for intelliJ somehow?

Comment: Which version of IDEA? 10+ at lest has git support

Comment: @fge I am using IntelliJ of version 11, latest build (11.0.1)

Comment: You could try and go into the version control menu, normally it allows you to select a git root

Comment: @fge for some reason it doesn't allow me even to choose which version control system I am using. It selects Subversion and I don't know how to change it. There are no .svn folders anywhere under the source root.

Comment: I see no other way than recreating the project from the parent root then :/ Sorry I cannot help further

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I have successfully opened a Maven subproject within IDEA. Naturally, it hasn't enabled Git integration automatically. From VCS menu I have selected "Enable Version Control Integration" and chose "Git" from submenu.

Then IDEA complained that there is no .git folder within the project and offered to select parent .git folder. I did it and everything worked as expected.

If you don't have Git option in VCS menu, this might be a bug. Try to disable SVN plugin and see if that helps (I don't have SVN plugin in my IDEA).

Comment: Version 2020.2 - There is no "Enable Version Control Integration" option under "VCS".  It looks like the solution in this case is to go to File->Settings->Plugins->Git and enable it.

Answer (score 35):

You may need to add git to the list of version control in the settings

settings > Version Control

then make sure that git is listed in the table as a VCS

I had to do this otherwise git wasn't listed in the VCS menu in the menu bar.

[image: Make sure Git is in one of the columns here]

Comment: Works on IDEA v14.1.2 as well. Good job.

Comment: In my case I had BOTH git and svn listed for the current project on this screen and it was causing intelliJ to bork out. Removing svn allowed git to take control and intelliJ thus to  "know" the status of all files vis-à-vis the repository.

Comment: Works on IDEA v14.1.4 as well but still confusing. I wouldn't expect a module/project specific setting in the main settings view.

Answer (score 7):

Just delete .idea/vcs.xml and restart intelliJ

Comment: This works for me. I have a composite project including 3 subprojects(each one has a git repo), some how when I open the composite project in IDEA(2022.3!), it only recognized one of the 3 projects. I deleted vcs.xml, then restart, it recognized all 3 projects.

Answer (score 2):

It helped me, hope it will solve your issue

VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration

And then choose what you use

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, we had recently upgraded from CVS to GIT (gasp). There were some old CVS specific files in the project (i.e. .cvsignore) that must have indicated to IntelliJ that this was a CVS project. I had to manually remove this file for IntelliJ to recognize the new .git folder and related files.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was not able to get Intellij to detect Git on the module. So I removed the module from the project and re-added it. That time it was detected and I could use the Git menu.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that the Version Control tab is missing use View/Tool Windows/Version Control.

This will bring the Version Control window into the bottom frame, provided all the remaining pieces of your git configuration are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added a new Maven module to an existing multi-module project outside of IDEA. After importing the module into IDEA it refused to detect it as a Git project.
What helped was to add a VCS directory mapping entry:

-> Settings -> Version Control -> shows a list of the existing modules and their assigned VCS (Git)

-> Add the new directory by pressing the '+'-Button and assigning Git as its VCS

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to a missing mapping, so my module was marked as unregistered root. Once I added my project to the Directory mapping it worked.

-> Settings -> Version Control -> Directory mapping, Then select your project and click on the "+" button

Answer (score -3):

Consider using Git outside of the IDE. There are great efficiencies to be gained from the command line in Git.

Comment: I love CLI of git, however in IDEA I can see differences and update them ad-hoc in diff view with compilation and code completion. So having GIT support in such case would help me much.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How can you update the difference?

Comment: in IDEA I can hit Ctrl+K which will populate commit dialog, and list of changed files. Now I can choose changed file and click Ctrl+D, which will show me difference window. And this difference window allows me to change current file and highlight errors/code complete. And IDEA can optimize imports and reformat code on commit as well.

Comment: I'm just not getting when I would be in a commit window and have outstanding errors. Seems that you would be fixing those before you are in the commit window by pressing the short cut to go to the next error.

Comment: I believe that this is starting to be off-topic.

Comment: Yep, although I agree with @AdamDymitruk here: I use IDEA and git, but always commit from the command line. IDEA cannot do git add -p for instance. And I positively HATE side-by-side diffs :/

Comment: This just indicates a personal preference for cmd line. For me much easier and safer to commit from within IntelliJ and clearly see and amend/deselect all modified files.

Comment: It's a personal preference to use MS Paint instead of Photoshop. :)