# Add existing module under Subversion source control in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, svn, intellij-idea

I have a number of modules working nicely with the Changes tab, because I added them under source control *when I created their modules*.

- However, for one module I chose to skip adding under source control initially and now that I want to use the Changes tab to commit changes and similar with that too, I have not been able to find a way to add this existing module to work with the SVN plugin.
- Looked through the VCS menu, but I could not find ["Enable Version Control Integration" there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724748/adding-git-support-to-existing-project-in-intellij-idea)
- And could not find a place under Changes tab itself

Note the module folder itself is checked out externally with TortoiseSVN, exactly the same way as the other modules that I integrated with Subversion plugin on creation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set up the mappings in `File` | `Settings` | **Version Control**.

```
project directory <=> Subversion
```

Note that you can have several mappings there.

Comment: had to browse to the module folder there and it worked after refreshing changes! thanks