# Git option not available under Version Control in Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have installed Git on my local machine. I am using Git as a DVCS
 tool for bitbucket. I have the .git folder inside my project directory
 as I had cloned the project. I want to integrate Git into IntelliJ Idea but
 however, I am not able to see this option under the Version Control
 Integration as below.

[image: Git option not available under VCS]

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/24248800/4068218 is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to **File -> Settings** or (Ctrl + Atl + S) Then select **Plugins**

Ensure you have the Git Integration plugin enabled for Intellij as seen here (disabled in picture). Install if not already.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to **Settings** then click on **Version Control**.
add git in VCS column from + button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

incase it was working previously and stop working, then reimport your project:

- open intellij
- on right corner there is setting symbol
- click on it
- select option rebase
- make sure you have open your source tree with correct login credential

Answer (score 0):

For me, the plugin was already installed and enabled (as suggest in one answer). Also, I didn't see the same version control menu (as seen in another answer). I also tried re-importing my project to no avail (as suggested by a 3rd answer). Finally, I realized I needed to 'trust project' and that worked to allow me to see the Git menus.